# RSS feed notifier with easy StackExchange integration and proxy support

Tags: windows, rss

I'm looking for a good RSS feed notifier that has these features:

1. [Required] Windows software
2. [Required] Full proxy support for all sorts of passworded and not proxies
3. [Required] Ability to display notifications when new items show up in feeds.

   - Notifications should be able to be displayed in the corner of the screen, like new mail notifications in Outlook or RSS ones in [Feed Notifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/)
   - URL link so the post can be open from the notification in the browser
4. [Strongly desired] Proxy support should work **out of the box** the way it does in FireFox or Chrome, by using Windows's proxy settings; without the need to configure it manually.
5. [Strongly desired] Ability to NOT display notification for older posts.

   This is critical for SE where all RSS feeds are "post changes" based; and thus display old questions whenever someone edits the question or one of the answers... makes finding NEW questions to answer a drag and a half.
6. [Wanted] Easy integration with StackExchange. I don't want to hunt down every site's RSS URL if possible (just type site name and it generates "https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/feeds").
7. [Wanted] Configurable check period - per feed.

As mentioned in #3, I am already aware of [Feed Notifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/), but it's a pain when it comes to #4 and #5.

Comment: Just my guess with no real added value, but I really highly doubt anything covering step 6 exists. However, majority of RSS readers can autosniff feed url from HTML page (see `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml"...` in page source)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [FeedDemon](http://www.feeddemon.com/) and was happy with it. It does not have StackExchange specific features (#5 and #6), but otherwise it's good.

1. Windows software: check
2. Full proxy support: I think so, but can't really test that.
3. Notifications: check
4. Proxy support should work out of the box: check. Supports automatic detection and manual configuration.
5. Ability to NOT display notification for older posts: fail (I think). As a workaround (which fails step #6): `http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/feeds/newest` outputs only newest posts. With that, there's no need to filter notifications.
6. Easy integration with StackExchange: nope. Can sniff feed urls from pages, though (just copy and paste `http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/` and it'll get feed URL.
7. Configurable check period - per feed: not sure.

I don't currently have Windows computer, so I can't validate #7.